# Given matrix $A$ , need to find an invertible matrix $P$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $D=P^{-1} \cdot A\cdot P$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

> Given $A= $$\left(\begin{matrix}
> 2 & 0 & 0 \\
> 1 & 1 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & 2 \\
> \end{matrix} \right)
> $
> find an invertible matrix $P$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $D=P^{-1} \cdot A\cdot P$

First we need the Characteristic Polynomial $P(t)= |t\cdot I-A|$ $=$$\left(\begin{matrix}
t-2 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & t-1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & t-2 \\
\end{matrix} \right)
$
then calculate the determinant and we get - $P(t)= $$\left|\begin{matrix}
t-2 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & t-1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & t-2 \\
\end{matrix} \right|
$
$=(t-2)^2 \cdot (t-1)$

second thing is we find our eigenvalues so $P(t)=0$ and we will get $t=2$ or $t=1$

now need to find the eigenspace so for $t=2$ we get $P(2 \cdot I -A)=$  $\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix} \right)
$ let $y= \lambda$ and we get that the general solution is $(x,y,z)=(\lambda,\lambda,0)= \lambda (1,1,0)$so $V_2=Sp\{(1,1,0) \}$

now for $t=1$ we get $P(1 \cdot I -A)=$  $\left(\begin{matrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{matrix} \right)
$ from here we get
$P(1 \cdot I -A)=$  $\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix} \right)
$ so the solution is $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ I did not know how to continue as I noticed that my way is not right according to the textbook , This is the solution in the textbook:
for $2 \cdot I -A$ they got the same matrix $\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix} \right)
$ but the span is different the span they found is $V_2 = Sp {(1,1,0),(0,0,1)}$ my first question is why is that the span also has $(0,0,1)$? and then it also says that the set $\{(1,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ is a basis for $V_2$

and for $t=1$ they got the same matrix but also different span they got $V_1= Sp\{(0,1,0)\}$ and also they said that the set $\{(0,1,0)\}$ is a basis for $V_1$.

now the set $\{(1,1,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ is $\Bbb R^3$ basis that is made of eigenvectors therefore $P=$ $\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{matrix} \right)
$
is a Diagonalizable matrix for A and similar to the matrix $D=$  $\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{matrix} \right)
$

Can someone explain the solution to me ? I got lost on the spans mainly and the matrix $D$ and sorry for the English translations if they are not correct as I could not be 100% sure of the translations.
I also checked similar questions that I found but I did not find them helpful

Thank you!

Comment: The eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda = 2$ is not one-dimensional in this case. Likewise $\lambda = 1$ doesn't only give $(x, y, z) = (0, 0, 0)$. Revise your calculations of $(2 I - A) v = 0$ and $(1 I - A) v$ in both cases and you will find the right answer.

Comment: @prets for $V_1$ let $\lambda_1 =y$ since it is zero so it is a free variable and therefore we have $(x,y,z)=(\lambda_1(0,1,0)$ because $x=z=0$
and $V_2$ let $y=\lambda_2$ and $z=\lambda_3$ so we get $(x,y,z)=(\lambda_2,\lambda_2,0)+(0,0,\lambda_3)$? is this right? 
since in $V_2$ $z$ and $y$ are free variables and in $V_1$ $y$ is a free variable

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. And hopefully you see how those five you the same vectors as in the textbook?

Comment: @prets Yes thank you! the question is solved :) will upload my answer tomorrow as it is a bit different than the textbook so hopefully it can help someone as well